# Problema con border-color en card al usar linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient

estoy practicando CSS,y encuentro un problema a la hora de querer añadir bordes a un card que tengo; si coloco border-color: red por ejemplo, si me pinta los bordes de color rojo, pero cuando quiero usar linear-gradient (lo probé por defecto y usando -webkit-linear-gradient)  ya no funciona. Dejo el html y el css que tengo. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

HTML:

```
<div class="card h-100 border-instagram">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@realnathanf</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        11k
                        Followers
                        1099 Today
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .border-instagram {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(to rigth, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve buscando una solución a tu comentario: "solo el `border-top`". Cómo dije, no se puede colorear un `border` con varios colores; solo uno a la vez: `border-top-color`, `border-right-color`  etc. Pero aún así no se puede colorear con múltiples color con `border-top-color`.

Lo que Ice fue un truco muy satisfactorio que espero que te agrade.

- Al elemento `.border-instagram` le puse `position: relative` y `padding-top: 5px`
- Creé una nueva regla al elemento `.border-instagram` con el seudo elemento: `::before` y, trabaje con ella.

Queda así:

```
.border-instagram { /* importante para el seudo elemento: ::before */
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.border-instagram::before {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5px;
 background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}
```

Con `padding-top: 5px` y `height: 5px` podés cambiar de ancho del "*border"*. A partir de esto  está a tu cargo echarle fuego a la mecha y **acción!**.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que tenía en mente realizar, ya que me ayudaste a entender que bg-color no acepta gradient. Muchas gracias Narciso

Answer (score 0):

No se puede colorear un borde con varios colores con **CSS**; solo un color y de la siguiente manera (como ejemplo):

```
.border {
  border: 2px solid #123;
 }
```

El estilo del color de Instagram es **background**. Y podés usar el estilo así:

```
.border-instagram {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 40px;
  linear-height: 240px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #d6249f;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  /*box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);*/
}
```

Ya te toca el estilo dentro de la **card** `.border-instagram`. pero el `background` debe ser así.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, el tema es que necesito sólo el borde de arriba con ese estilo y no el background del card. Pero muchas gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad border-color no se utiliza para generar degradado a los bordes. Te paso la solucion que he creído mas útil y sencilla, en la que se genera un borde al DIV en una sola clase.

```css
.border-instagram {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(100, 91, 83) 0%, rgb(235, 82, 82) 18.23%, rgb(247, 143, 47) 34.37%, rgb(244, 193, 81) 48.96%, rgb(82, 187, 118) 66.15%, rgb(38, 165, 215) 82.29%, rgb(224, 105, 183) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="border-instagram">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@realnathanf</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
                11k
                Followers
                1099 Today
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Buenos dias, muchas gracias por tu aporte Santi. Lo que necesitaba era saber si habia alguna forma de sólo pintar con gradient el borde de arriba, pero por lo que veo no se puede usar gradient, a no ser que se lo adapte de otra forma. Igualmente te agradezco.